# Prove a function gets a maximum in $(0,\infty)$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives, continuity

I've been trying to solve this problem:

> Let $f(x) = \frac {x}{x+sin x}$, prove the function receives a maximum in $(0,\infty)$

I've proven the function is uniformly continuous in $(0,\infty)$. But I'm not sure how to prove it gets a Maximum.

I've thought about Weierstrass, but I'm limited to a non-closed segment $(0,\infty)$

I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: Prove that there is a compact subinterval of $(0,\infty)$ that must contain the maximum. This is easy to do by finding an $x\in[a,b]\subset(0,\infty)$ such that for any $y\in(0,\infty)\setminus[a,b]$, $f(y)\leq f(x)$.

Comment: @DonThousand I can understand logically that if I choose $[a,b]$ where $a = \pi, b= 2\pi$, the maximum exists there. But I'm struggling with a formal proof. Can you maybe help me word it better? Thanks Don.

Answer (score 1):

I would show that the limit for $x\rightarrow \infty$ of $f$ goes to 1. Then by definition of the limit you know $|f(x) -1|<\varepsilon $ for all $\varepsilon>0$ and $x>R$ for some $R>0$. Pick some $\varepsilon$ and corresponding $R$. Pick a suitable $a<R$, for example $\pi$. On $[R,\infty)$ you now have $f(x)<1+\varepsilon$. Furthermore $[a,R]$ is a compact set and $f$ is continuous so $f$ attains a maximum on $[a,R]$, say $M$. Show that $f$ is injective on $(0,a]$. Now you have $f(x) \leqslant \max(f(a), M,1+\varepsilon)$ on $(0,\infty)$.

Edit: One final remark that I just realised would be easier than showing $f$ is injective on $(0,a]$ for some $a$. You can use that $\sin(x) > \frac{x}{2}$ on $(0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ to bound the function $f$ from above. Then simply pick $a=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and thus $f(x) \leqslant \frac{3}{2}$ on $(0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$.